# how to maintain new id with javascript/Jquery function call for dynamically inserted html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I add some form inputs with dynamically inserted html elements in bootstrap.As a beginner, I use datepicker.js & Jquery function
to display calendar for every every Date input field.
The date-picker works fine for other static fields.
But if i try to add dynamically inserted html elements,then date-picker does not work for that new element.
also new elements alignment slightly get shift to right.

Please check image given below:

[image]

I don't know how to maintain new & easy id for new elements.
Also I don't know how to call same Jquery function for all new elements.
I think, these things are creating that problem
please tell me how to fix this.

Here is the source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Information</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      
      <!--Sorry: i didn't find online links for the links below -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
      <script src="js/moment.min.js"></script> <!-- bootstrap-datetimepicker requires Moment.js to be loaded first -->
      <script src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
      
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({format:"DD/MM/YYYY", useCurrent: false });
         });    
         
         //this will be called for new datetimepicker.i think, unique id needed every time.
         $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({format:"DD/MM/YYYY", useCurrent: false });
         });            
      </script>  
      
      <style>
         div.child_div:first-child {
         margin-top: 0px;
         padding-top: 0px;
         }
         div.child_div {
         width: 615px;
         }
         div.job-position {
         width: 220px;
         }
         div.job-type {
         width: 180px;
         }
         div.job-amount {
         width: 180px;
         }
         div.form-group {
         padding-top: 25px;
         }
         input#create_button {
         margin-top: 50px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body >
      <div class="container"  >
         <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
               <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;"><b>Information</b></h3>
               </div>
               <div class="panel-body">
                  <form class="form-horizontal" >
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3"  for="employeeid">ID:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                           <div class="input-group">
                              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"  aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="employeeid"  placeholder="Enter ID">             
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group" id="parent_div1">
                        <div class="row form-group" id="child_div1">
                           <label  class="col-xs-2 control-label"></label>
                           <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3">
                              <label  class="wb-inv">Job:</label>
                              <div class="input-group" style="">
                                 <select class="form-control " id="employeetype" onchange="updateText('facultyinstitute')">
                                    <option value="" disabled="" selected=""  >Select Job Type</option>
                                    <option value="10">Type 1</option>
                                    <option value="10">Type 2</option>
                                 </select>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3" >
                              <label  class="wb-inv"> Effective Date:</label>
                              <div class="input-group" >
                                 <input type="text"  id='datetimepicker1' class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
                                 <span class="input-group-addon">
                                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                 </span>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3">
                              <label class="wb-inv">Amount:</label>
                              <div class="input-group" >
                                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pamount" placeholder=".00" />
                                 <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i></span>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group"  style="padding-left:200px;">
                        <div class="form-group" id="parent_div">
                           <div class="row form-group child_div">
                              <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 job-position">
                                 <label for="form-input-col-xs-2" class="wb-inv">Other Job Position:</label>
                                 <div class="input-group" style="">
                                    <select class="form-control " id="employeetype" onchange="updateText('')">
                                       <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select Job Type</option>
                                       <option value="10">1</option>
                                       <option value="10">2</option>
                                       <option value="10">3</option>
                                    </select>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 job-date">
                                 <label for="form-input-col-xs-3" class="wb-inv">Date:</label>
                                 <div class="input-group">
                                 <!-- its duplicate is not working -->
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datetimepicker2" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" />
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 job-amount">
                                 <label for="form-input-col-xs-3" class="wb-inv">Amount:</label>
                                 <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-input-col-xs-3" placeholder=".00" />
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i></span>          
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group ">
                                 <div class="input-group">
                                    <input class="btn btn-danger deleteButton" type="button" value="-" />       
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <input class="btn btn-success " type="button" id="create_button" value="+" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                           <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
                           <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                           <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Exit</button> 
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </form>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script  type="text/javascript">     
         $('#create_button').click(function() {
           var html = $('.child_div:first').parent().html();
           $(html).insertBefore(this);
         });
         
         $(document).on("click", ".deleteButton", function() {
           $(this).closest('.child_div').remove();
         }); 
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

please let me know if any further information is required.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you added the new HTML the datepicker was not initialized for them so you need to reinitialize it, A good way is instead of `initializing` datepicker on `#datetimepicker1` and `#datetimepicker2`, intialize them on a class. Give both the `input` fields a `class` say `datetimepicker` then initialize them as

```
$(function () {
      $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({format:"DD/MM/YYYY", useCurrent: false });
});
```

and then initialize it again when you adding the `html`:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">     
         $('#create_button').click(function() {
           var html = $('.child_div:first').parent().html();
           $(html).insertBefore(this);
           // Reinitialize after inserting the HTML
           $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({format:"DD/MM/YYYY", useCurrent: false });
         });

         $(document).on("click", ".deleteButton", function() {
           $(this).closest('.child_div').remove();
         }); 
</script>
```

**My call is never keep id if you are cloning that element again, Selectors are so smart that you can pick any element without using id.**

Comment: Thanks @void it works fine.problem solved & i learned that trick.However,can you also tell me, that how i access them individually if i need to put them  in any  database.Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Information</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!--Sorry: i didn't find online links for the links below -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
  <script src="js/moment.min.js"></script> <!-- bootstrap-datetimepicker requires Moment.js to be loaded first -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


  <style>
     div.child_div:first-child {
     margin-top: 0px;
     padding-top: 0px;
     }
     div.child_div {
     width: 615px;
     }
     div.job-position {
     width: 220px;
     }
     div.job-type {
     width: 180px;
     }
     div.job-amount {
     width: 180px;
     }
     div.form-group {
     padding-top: 25px;
     }
     input#create_button {
     margin-top: 50px;
     }
  </style>
</head>
<body >
  <div class="container"  >
     <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
           <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;"><b>Information</b></h3>
           </div>
           <div class="panel-body">
              <form class="form-horizontal" >
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-3"  for="employeeid">ID:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                       <div class="input-group">
                          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"  aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="employeeid"  placeholder="Enter ID">             
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group" id="parent_div1">
                    <div class="row form-group" id="child_div1">
                       <label  class="col-xs-2 control-label"></label>
                       <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3">
                          <label  class="wb-inv">Job:</label>
                          <div class="input-group" style="">
                             <select class="form-control " id="employeetype" onchange="updateText('facultyinstitute')">
                                <option value="" disabled="" selected=""  >Select Job Type</option>
                                <option value="10">Type 1</option>
                                <option value="10">Type 2</option>
                             </select>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3" >
                          <label  class="wb-inv"> Effective Date:</label>
                          <div class="input-group" >
                             <input type="text"  id='datetimepicker1' class="form-control date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
                             <span class="input-group-addon">
                             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                             </span>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3">
                          <label class="wb-inv">Amount:</label>
                          <div class="input-group" >
                             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pamount" placeholder=".00" />
                             <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i></span>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group"  style="padding-left:200px;">
                    <div class="form-group" id="parent_div">
                       <div class="row form-group child_div">
                          <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 job-position">
                             <label for="form-input-col-xs-2" class="wb-inv">Other Job Position:</label>
                             <div class="input-group" style="">
                                <select class="form-control " id="employeetype" onchange="updateText('')">
                                   <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select Job Type</option>
                                   <option value="10">1</option>
                                   <option value="10">2</option>
                                   <option value="10">3</option>
                                </select>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 job-date">
                             <label for="form-input-col-xs-3" class="wb-inv">Date:</label>
                             <div class="input-group">
                             <!-- its duplicate is not working -->
                                <input type="text" class="form-control date" id="datetimepicker2" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 job-amount">
                             <label for="form-input-col-xs-3" class="wb-inv">Amount:</label>
                             <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-input-col-xs-3" placeholder=".00" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i></span>          
                             </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group ">
                             <div class="input-group">
                                <input class="btn btn-danger deleteButton" type="button" value="-" />       
                             </div>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <input class="btn btn-success " type="button" id="create_button" value="+" />
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Exit</button> 
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </form>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <script  type="text/javascript">     
     $('#create_button').click(function() {
       var html = $('.child_div:first').parent().html();
       $(html).insertBefore(this);
     });

     $(document).on("click", ".deleteButton", function() {
       $(this).closest('.child_div').remove();
     }); 
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).on('click','.date',function(){
                   $(this).datepicker({
                   format:"DD/MM/YYYY",
                   useCurrent: false
                 }).blur().focus();
     });         
  </script>  

  </script>
```